# How do I return a string from my async function using the request API?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I am trying to do is print the HTML code source as a sting using the request API, I've declared a function that fetches the data as a string put when I print the output, it returns undefined. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

file1.js

```
const request = require('request');

var test = getMovieTitles();
var output;

test.then(function(result) {
    output = result;
})

//prints undefined
console.log(output);


async function getMovieTitles(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request('https://www.google.com',function nes(err, res, body) {  
        resolve(body);
        });
    })
}

module.export = test
```

file2.js

```
var sourceFile = require('./run.js');

sourceFile.test.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this part of your code is still asynchronously run

```java
test.then(function(result) {
    output = result;
})
```

so the `java console.log()` will fire before this callback is fired and the output variable has the data from the result callback function parameter.

to solve this just put the console.log() inside the .then() function's callback paramater

```java
test.then(function(result) {
    output = result;
    console.log(output); 
})
```

Comment: I will not be able to access the output variable from another file if it is inside test.then

Comment: to have access to the data on another  file export the test object to that other file and do the then request on that file

Comment: can I export that object in my function or can I do it in the main? Thanks

Comment: you just have to add the code ```module.export = test ``` on the last line of the file

Comment: I've updated the code but it returns `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` in file2. The end result I'd like to do is you pass the HTML code into a string so I don't have to use the `test.then` call each time.

Comment: I see that you edited the code... your mistake was on the second file 'file2.js'. in file two you require the file1 ```var sourceFile = require('./file1.js')``` then for the callback just type ```sourceFile.then(function(result){console.log(result)})```, the module.exprot is the exported value when required. so then you set the module.export object to test the test variable is no longer needed. the require will give you the test variable directly to the assigned variable in file two. sorry for the late reply

Comment: I'm a little confused why it is `sourceFile.then` and not `sourceFile.test.then` since I've exported my `test` variable? All I get is : `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: shouldn't it be `module.export.test = test` in file1?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks!